# Add/remove class after click angular link

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

I have problem and question to  my angularJS code.  So, I need set new class after click link. My main problem is it, that I have some links in angular and a few in php.

Example;

```
<li
    <a  href="/somelink>angular link</a>

</li>
  <li
    <a  href="/somelink2>angular link 2</a>

</li>
  <li
    <a  href="/somelink3>angular link 3</a>

</li>

  <li
    <a  href="/somelink 4> Normal link - reload page</a>

</li>
```

code which set class on the current link after reload page

```
  var selector = $('a[href^="' + $(location).attr('href') + '"]');
  selector.addClass('LinkToMenu').parent().addClass('menu-active-border')
```

I wrote a some jquery code which add class after realod page to current adres, but i have now two problems;

1 If I'm on php page and click angular page, browser  realod page and my link gets  needed classs - it's ok, but now if I try click other angular page I can't remove this class, how do it ?

2 I wrote some angular code which (example above) add class after click angular link, but it causes problems because if I try move from php page to angular page class is set before reload page yet.

summary;

1 FROM php page -> angular view I need set class after reload page, not immediately after click.
2 change class after click angular link (immediately), remove older and add current class.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're asking how to add and remove CSS classes in angularjs. You can use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) to add conditional classes.

```
<a href="/somelink2" ng-class="{'menu-active-border': isLinkActive('/somelink2')}">angular link 2</a>
```

Where your function isLinkActive would look something like this:

```
$scope.isLinkActive = function(path) {
  return $location.path() == path;
}
```

Another option is to create your own directive and manipulate classes there:

`<a href="/somelink" highlight-if-active></a>`

```
myApp.directive('highlightIfActive', [function($location){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            if ($location.href() == $attrs.href) {
              $element.addClass('menu-active-border');
            } else {
              $element.removeClass('menu-active-border');
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```